# Google Chrome cast isn't playing the Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cast

I'm developing an iOS APP to cast the videos via Chromecast from iPhone-iOS App. Integrated the Google Chrome cast SDKv4. The Cast button discovers the receivers but it doesn't display the video, but video is playing in the iPhone

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/mp4/DesigningForGoogleCast.mp4"];

AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];
player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
controller.view.frame = _localPlayerView.frame;
controller.player = player;
controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;

GCKMediaMetadata *metadata =
[[GCKMediaMetadata alloc] initWithMetadataType:GCKMediaMetadataTypeMovie          ];
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInfo = [[GCKMediaInformation alloc]
                                  initWithContentID:[videoURL absoluteString]
                                  streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeBuffered
                                  contentType:@"video/mp4"
                                  metadata:metadata
                                  streamDuration:100
                                  mediaTracks:nil
                                  textTrackStyle:nil
                                  customData:nil];

GCKCastSession *session =
[GCKCastContext sharedInstance].sessionManager.currentCastSession;

[[GCKCastContext sharedInstance].sessionManager addListener:self];
[session.remoteMediaClient loadMedia:mediaInfo];
[session start];
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error log?

Comment: Issue has been fixed. Thanks for your anticipation